# Has anyone successfully integrated chat with redmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chat, redmine, redmine-plugins

I was thinking that it would be cool if I could have a chat app as part of the interface for my Redmine installation. I did find a [plugin](http://github.com/jbrien/redmine-chat-plugin/tree) that works with [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) but it seems a while since there has been any downloads or updates of it and I'm reluctant to dive in. Has anyone tried this or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy to roll your own chat app using http://pusherapp.com, a sort of hosted websocket service.  You can see an example of the one I built at http://wetcamp.us.  If you're still interested in building out a chat app, I'd be happy to go into more detail on how I built mine.  But I noticed this is an old question, so you've probably moved on...

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Redmine but here is my two cents - when I checked on Juggernaut last it seemed outdated, maybe you could try [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/)? Also here is a tutorial on how to use it in a rails app: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=1033

Answer (score 0):

Eayredmine has a [chat plugin](http://www.easyredmine.com/online-store/easy-redmine-plugins/chat-real-time-messages-2)  but you have first to purchase the core easyredmine package to be able to use it.